# jsdoc alias method names

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

When using [jsdoc](https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc) to document your JavaScript modules, is it possible to set alias method names? For example, I have a method like this:

```
/**
* @name MyModule#save
*/
MyModule.prototype.save = function(...) {
  ...
}
```

But my module has alias methods of `save()`, like `cache()`, `put()`, `set()`, etc. They are simply convenience methods so that the developer has a choice of method names to use.

```
MyModule.prototype.set = function(...) {
   return this.save(...);
}
```

Anyways, is there any way to document these properly in jsdoc syntax? Something where the documentation will show up as `Alias of save()` or something along those lines.

There is an `@alias` tag in jsdoc, but I don't believe it does what I'm looking for.

Comment: I, too, am wondering this. `@alias` completely removes the function from the generated documentation. For your example, `set` would not be included, and `save` would make no note of being able to also call `set`. How can this information be documented?

Comment: I think that a `@aliasOf` tag should be added to the jsdoc spec for such cases.

Answer (score 1):

If I got your question correctly, the only solution for your problem is the [@borrows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50125881/8851581) tag .