# How to document a method with multiple aliases?

Tags: javascript, documentation, jsdoc, jsdoc3

I'm trying to document the **getName()** method of The following Person constructor :

**Javascript code :**

```
/**
 * Creates a person instance.
 * @param {string} name The person's full name.
 * @constructor
 */
function Person( name ) {

    /**
     * Returns the person's full name.
     * @return {string} The current person's full name.
     */
    function getName() {
        return name;
    }

    this.getName = getName;
    this.getN = getName;
    this.getFullName = getName;
}
```

As you can see, the **getName()** method has two aliases ( **getN()** and **getFullName()** ), so the obvious tag to use is the [@alias](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-alias.html) tag, but unfortunately, it has two major problems :

> 1- It tells JSDoc to **rename** the method.
>
> 2- It can't be used for **multiple aliases**.

Is there any official way to document these kind of methods ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to this question may sound a bit funny but, actually, there is an official way to document method aliases, and they call it [@borrows](https://jsdoc.app/tags-borrows) .

> The **@borrows** tag allows you to add documentation for another symbol to
> your documentation.
>
> This tag would be useful if you had **more than one way to reference a
> function**, but you didn't want to duplicate the same documentation in
> two places.

So, the **getName()** should be documented as follows:

**Javascript code :**

```
/**
 * Creates a person instance.
 * @param {string} name The person's full name.
 * @constructor
 * @borrows Person#getName as Person#getN
 * @borrows Person#getName as Person#getFullName
 */
function Person( name ) {

    /**
     * Returns the person's full name.
     * @return {string} The current person's full name.
     * @instance
     * @memberof Person
     */
    function getName() {
        return name;
    }

    this.getName = getName;
    this.getN = getName;
    this.getFullName = getName;
}
```

**JSDoc result :**

[image: Result]